# How can I create custom gift basket for user in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I want to create a gift basket where it has a fixed price and this basket has 20-30 products. But user can select  only 6 from this basket to purchase.

How can I create this functionality in shopify.

Comment: Hi Harry!  I work at Bold Commerce, one of the app providers in the Shopify ecosystem, and one of my colleagues has developed a "Chocolate Box" modification/plugin for our Product Options app that would do exactly what you're looking for. If it's something that interests you, feel free to contact support@boldcommerce.com for details to see if it's a solution that would fit your situation.

Comment: @DaveB Thanks for your response. But they provide paid apps. And I cannot afford these apps. Do you have any Idea, How can I create Bundle products. So, I could try some another solution.

Comment: Hm. Are you looking to allow customers to pick the same product for the basket multiple times, or will it be limited to a max of 1 for each of the component products?  Do you need inventory tracking for the component products, or is having them just as line item properties good enough?

Comment: @DaveB I want to limit 1 same product in one basket and want to track inventory as well.

Comment: Then you could probably use the `name=id[]` notation, probably on some checkboxes... That would be a way to get all the variant IDs to submit, and it would only take a little piece of javascript to enforce the quantity 6 rule...